# Can Java reflection be debugged?

Tags: java, eclipse, reflection

I'm not terribly good with Java reflection, and I'm trying to debug an ugly piece of code that uses a good amount of reflection. I placed a breakpoint on some methods that should be called, but the code never pauses when I execute the program. So, this has led me to believe that running a method using reflection ignores breakpoints when running in Eclipse (Indigo on Windows 7).

Can anyone confirm this? I've provided an example below, although since I don't know how to execute a method particular to a class using reflection, it doesn't work, but I hope it clarifies what I'm asking in my question:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    try
    {
        Class test = Class.forName("Test");

        test.runMethodDoSomething();
    }
    catch (ClassNotFoundException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static class Test
{
    public void doSomething()
    {
        // Place breakpoint here.
    }
}
```

Comment: I cannot confirm this! I had worked with reflection intensively. debugging did always work. But your code does not even compile!!!

Comment: You can debug any Java code with a decent debugger (I use Eclipse and NetBeans IDEs and their respectively debuggers). Maybe the problem is that you're running this code (not debugging) or it's not getting called at all. If you want to make sure about it, place simple `System.out.println("Reflection call!");` or similar to know that the code has been executed.

Comment: Cant confirm it either, I've done the core of a metadata-based object merging utility for an application I worked in with pure reflection and debugging saved my life one too many times.

Comment: Yeah, I was able to get a test going. I'll attempt to close the question now.

Comment: But in this code sample the method is no method been reflectively invoked.

Comment: Note - method breakpoints are set the most easily in the Outline view.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, reflection does not conflict with debugger. Typically you can put breakpoint in method, then invoke it using reflection and debugger will stop there.

Second, there is not reflection in your code snippet. `Class.forName()` is dynamic class loading. Reflection is when you are using `obj.getClass().getMethod("myMethod").invoke()`.

So, if your code snippet does not work try to understand problem in either your environment or probably in your code. Is there a chance that some kind of exception is thrown before you are calling the method but the exception is caught without notifications?

Comment: Yeah, you're last comment got it. The Exceptions weren't printing the stack trace, and that's why the code wasn't executing. Thanks ALex